# Render Sudo without a runtime upgrade

Tags: sudo

Is there a way to render Sudo unusable without a runtime upgrade like setting the Sudo key to something nobody knows the private key to?

Answer (score 6):

The suggestion of setting the Sudo key to something like the address with all 1's sounds reasonable, although I would suggest in the long term to remove the pallet using a runtime upgrade if you intend not to use it.

It may be possible the existence of the Sudo pallet on chains which have a transferable currency would be scrutinized under financial regulation, but I am not a lawyer, so what do I know?

Note, while on chains like Ethereum, it may be more popular to use the all 0 address, the private key to this public key is known for SR25519 and ED25519, so you definitely do not want to use it there.